# How to replace calc() with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

Right now some very important calculations on my site are done with html5 calc(). However I would like to replace them with jquery for older browsers. The CSS Looks like this:

```
.sampleClass {float:left;}

@media all and (min-width: 1500px){

.sampleClass {float:none;}
#wrapper.wrapSide{
    right:calc(1875px - 50%);
    right:-moz-calc(1875px - 50%);
    right:-webkit-calc(1875px - 50%);
}
.blogGallItems .blogImg {
    margin:0 0 0 calc(0.5% - 600px);
    margin:0 0 0 -moz-calc(0.5% - 600px);
    margin:0 0 0 -webkit-calc(0.5% - 600px);
}
.prev{
    left:calc(50% - 675px);
    left:-moz-calc(50% - 675px);
    left:-webkit-calc(50% - 675px);
}
.next{
    left:calc(50% + 600px);
    left:-moz-calc(50% + 600px);
    left:-webkit-calc(50% + 600px);
}

}
```

I am trying somthing like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(".sampleClass").css("float") == "none" ){
        $('#wrapper.wrapSide').css('right', '1875px').css('right', '-=50%');
    }
});
```

Well It doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you are setting the same property twice. The second overrides the first one.

`$(element).css('right', (parseInt($(element).css('right')) * 0.5) + 'px');`
seems more logical to me.

or

```
var right = parseInt($(element).css('right'));
el.css('right', (right * 0.5) + 'px');
```